# strpos not working with $post method

Tags: php, strpos

I have a IF Statement where when i submit my page it is going to check if the time exists already and if so assign a value to my variable or echo out a message saying it found the time. Doesnt seem to be working though, i tried == true and !== false but no luck.

Below is code thanks.

```
$alarm = $_POST[add];
$alarms = explode("\n", shell_exec("crontab -l")); //grab schdules
array_pop($alarms); //remove empty last line

foreach($alarms as $alarm)
{
    if (strpos($alarm, $alarm['alarmhour']) !== false)
    {
        $HourSuccess = "Correct";
        $message121 = "We found the same time.. ";
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message121');</script>";
    }
}
```

`$alarm['alarmhour']` is my post method which will have a value of 1-23.
`$alarm` is looping through my schedules and i have one in there lets say for 2 o clock. If i type two and try run, it doesnt find it?

P.s: When i echo out my `$alarm['alarmhour']` it returns the value i entered correctly.

Comment: What's the meaning of this line? `$HourSuccess = "Correct";`

Comment: I have a if statement to say if that above is correct then dont go ahead with the rest else continue

Comment: `if ($HourSuccess == "Correct") //If same Hour then throw error
 {
  $msg =  "ERROR! Your Start Hour conflicts with another schedule. Please ensure they dont conflict.";
 }`

Comment: use booleans instead. That way you can use `if($HourSuccess)` directly. Or, if you didn't define `$HourSuccess` above that, just use `if(isset($HourSuccess))`, storing any non-null values you like (conventionally `true`) into `HourSuccess` when successful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You defined `$alarm` twice.

The first line defines `$alarm` as the value of a value from `$_POST`, which is OK.

The foreach line iterates `$alarms` with each value being stored to `$alarm`, which is also correct. But it will overwrite the original value.

Look at this line:

```
if(strpos($alarm, $alarm['alarmhour']) !== false)
```

Don't you think there is a problem using the same variable differently?

Instead, you should probably give a new name to the variable defined on line 1 (e.g. `$postedAlarm`), and refactor correct usages in lines below.

Comment: Thats exactly it! To be honest, was pulling my hair out over this and was staring right at me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your first line `$alarm = $_POST[add];` should be corrected as `$alarm = $_POST["add"];`

Comment: This would only prevent a warning, but not solve the ultimate problem.

Comment: Exactly as PE said.. Thats not the matter and thats just a typo of me writing this post.